# Во время игры на зарядке ноутбук через какое-то время выключается

Tags: ноутбук

Я заметил, что когда я играю в игру на зарядке, то ноутбук через некоторое время выключается, как будто выключили электричество. Но после этого я могу включить его обратно сразу. Когда я играл от батареи, то этой проблемы не заметил. Это началось недавно. Не знаю, что делать, прежде чем в сервисный центр отнести.

Comment: Если только в играх - перегрев

Comment: Обновил текст ответа. Дайте знать, помогло ли:-) Мне лично помог мощный домашний пылесос.

Answer (score 3):

1. Проверьте, не перегревается ли ноутбук (при зарядке идет дополнительный нагрев). Наиболее вероятная причина. 90 градусов Цельсия - опасный предел, как помню.
2. Проверьте, все ли открыты вентиляционные отверстия (мягкая поверхность - самая частая причина). В сочетании с пунктами 1 и 3 может давать выключение из-за перегрева.
3. Проверьте, не скопилась ли пыль на вентиляторе. Опять же сочетание с пунктами 1 и 2 может ухудшать ситуацию. Можно не открывать сразу, а мощным пылесосом попробовать вытянуть пыль.
4. Проверьте соответствие драйверов.
5. Могла высохнуть термопаста на кулере. Поищите в сети, как определить и что делать в этом случае.

Comment: Здравствуйте) Я недавно чистил ноутбук от пыли, и менял термопасту. Паста нормальная, mx-4. Играю на столе. Перегрева не наблюдалось: температуры держатся в районе 70-75 градусов. Спасибо за предположение